# ejabberd-13.10 server is not started in ubuntu?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I have installed ejabberd-13.10 in ubuntu 13.04. But it throws following error, when I start ejabberd server from from terminal by issuing ejabberdctl start command.
       root@localhost:/home/livin/Desktop/ejabberd13.10/# ejabberdctl start.

The error I am getting (in ejabberd log file)  is "ejabberd:exit_or_halt:124 failed to start application 'p1_mysql': {error,{"no such file or directory","p1_mysql.app"}}".

How to solve it?

Comment: Please format your error message to be readable in same way you see ti.

Comment: Just a general comment @BABUK: it's much better, if you answer your own question, to post the answer rather than edit the question. It's clearer for others who may have the same question how to solve it and you get more points for it! It's perfectly reasonable to accept your own answer...

Answer (score 2):

p1_pgsql is not part of your release. run

```
./configure --enable-odbc --enable-pgsql 
make
make install
```

This will make sure p1_pgsql is added to rebar/reltool

Answer (score 2):

BABU K, the solution you suggested is useless for me ,because make command has the below restriction. 
"/usr/local/lib/erlang/bin/escript rebar skip_deps=true compile"

besides : thanks to [@BABU K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1744375/babu-k), with his solution I did't success at first ,and Then I check the rebar.config.script ,and the 55 lines
 `Deps = [{p1_mysql,".*",{git,"git://github.com/processone/mysql"}},
        {p1_cache_tab, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/processone/cache_tab"}},
        {p1_tls, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/processone/tls"}},
        {p1_stringprep, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/processone/stringprep"}},
        {p1_xml, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/processone/xml"}},
        {p1_yaml, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/processone/p1_yaml"}},
        {xmlrpc, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/rds13/xmlrpc"}}],`

is missed the first line p1_mysql ,after I add it ,compile successed .

if some of you used the BABUK's way still failed you can check my suggestion.

Comment: Please don't use answers to post your problems or questions - only solutions do problems. In this case, you should comment instead.

Comment: Sorry,I am new to the comment rules. I will pay attention to that next time.

Answer (score 1):

1.First add p1_mysql's url to lists:flatmap() function of rebar.config.script file,

```
CfgDeps = lists:flatmap(
            fun({mysql, true}) ->
                    [{p1_mysql, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/processone/mysql"}}];
               ({pgsql, true}) ->
                    [{p1_pgsql, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/processone/pgsql"}}];
               ({pam, true}) ->`enter code here`
                    [{p1_pam, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/processone/epam"}}];
               ({zlib, true}) ->
                    [{p1_zlib, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/processone/zlib"}}];
               ({stun, true}) ->
                    [{p1_stun, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/processone/stun"}}];
               ({json, true}) ->
                    [{jiffy, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/davisp/jiffy"}}];
               ({iconv, true}) ->
                    [{p1_iconv, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/processone/eiconv"}}];
               ({http, true}) ->
                    [{ibrowse, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse"}},
                     {lhttpc, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/esl/lhttpc"}}];
               ({lager, true}) ->
                    [{lager, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/basho/lager"}}];
               ({lager, false}) ->
                    [{p1_logger, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/processone/p1_logger"}}];
               (_) ->
                    []`enter code here`
            end, Cfg)
```

2.After adding URL to lists:flatmap function, Add a folder named as p1_mysql in deps folder of ejabberd-13.10 and place files downloaded from github.com/processone/mysql link. and create ebin directory in p1_mysql folder where beam files will be generated after compiling ejabberd.

3.Then finally run ejabberd-13.10 by issuing ./rebar get-deps , and compile(make), and install beam files by make install.

4.Now start ejabberd server.